# How can I make provision on a port other than ttyUSB0?

Tags: provisioning, toit

In the case of ***provisioning***, the port is means ***/dev/tty***? How should the "***toit serial provision...***" command look like if you need to use not the standard, as I understand it, ***ttyUSB0*** port, but, for example, ***ttyACM0***?
Naturally, I can use the ***Toit Console Serial*** option, but how do I do it from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom port using `toit serial provision --port`.

This can also be done for all the other serial commands like monitor `toit serial monitor --port /dev/ttyUSB0`.

If you want what ports are available you can run: `toit serial ports`.